# How must one implement a has_many alike system for different kind of models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have several kinds of `Orders`; they differ quite a lot in the attributes and behaviour; but they share a common interface (Duck). Roughly like so:

```
class PackageOrder
  has_one :package

  def line_items
    [package, package.site.first]
  end
end

class SiteOrder
  has_one :site

  def line_items
    [site]
  end
end

class Customer
  has_many :package_orders
  has_many :site_orders
end
```

Is there a way to abstract the various `orders` on Customer? So that I can say active-recordy things like:

```
Customer.orders
Customer.orders << PackageOrder.new
```

And that I don't have to add a `has_many` line whenever I introduce a new `Order` variation?

I am not too familiar with all the possible usages of Polymorphic associations, so perhaps that offers a solution? Is this feasible at all?

I could, obviously, do some magic on `Customer` (pseudocode warning)

```
class Customer
  ORDER_TYPES = [:package_order, :site_order]
  class_eval.do 
    ORDER_TYPES.each {|type| has_many type.pluralize.to_sym}
  end

  def orders
    ORDER_TYPES.map {|type| self.type.pluralize }.flatten
  end
end
```

But I am wondering if ActiveRecord or Rails does not already offer something for me:

Comment: Looks like you want a polymorphic association.

Comment: Isn't that the other way around? Like when you want one generic `Image` being able to belong_to both a `Post` and a `Page`. Or is it perfectly possible to use polymorphic associations with has_many? And if so, how?

Comment: Yes it'd need to have a `belongs_to` but you can do that with an orders model which is polymorphic and belongs to either a `PackageOrder` or a `SiteOrder` then you can either see which model the order is associated to and use that or delegate from the order to the associated model.  You can also then add on has_many through relationships if you ever need to query for a specific order type.  I'll leave it to you to decide which approach you think is cleaner.